# swift optional var in @objc protocol

Tags: swift, swift2

I am a swift beginner (my background is VBA, VB.NET). I first found the double optional variable (??) confusing when using the window variable on the UIApplicationDelegate (.window??) object. After some research I understand that a variable can be declared to be optional in a protocol as well as return an optional type.

One way to safely use the variable would be:

```
 if let checkHasVar = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window {
        if let varIsSomething = checkHasVar {
            //window exists and is referencing an object
        }
    }
```

Another would be:

```
 guard let hasWindowVar = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window,  window = hasWindowVar else {
        return
    }
```

Both work fine but I would be interested to learn whether this is a sensible approach to dealing with double optionals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're many approaches.

`if let` ...

```
if let windowProperty = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window {
  if let window = windowProperty {
    print(window)
  }
}
```

Chained `if let` ...

```
if let windowProperty = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window,
  window = windowProperty {
    print(window)
}
```

Pattern matching ...

```
if case .Some(let windowProperty) = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window,
  case .Some(let window) = windowProperty {
    print(window)
}
```

`guard` ...

```
guard let windowProperty = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window,
  window = windowProperty else {
    return
}
print(window)
```

You can combine them ...

```
if let windowProperty = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window,
  case .Some(let window) = windowProperty {
    print(window)
}
```

> Both work fine but I would be interested to learn whether this is a sensible approach to dealing with double optionals

Sensible? Does it work for you? Is your code readable? Do you understand it? Pick whatever you want, you like and use it.

This type of *questions* is going to lead to opinionated answers, which is not good. Lot of ways to do thing A and it's up to you what you're going to choose. No one can help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

`guard let = if not let`. With simple condition i advice you using `if let`, otherwise using `guard let`